# Altium: Polygon-Specific Rules

Tags: altium, design-rules, polygon

I am making a PCB where I want to have some polygons directly connect to all the components within them, and some to only relief connect. Normally this isn't an issue as I can just set up some design rules.

The problem is that in this specific case the polygons have the same net, so I can't do it by net or by net class. I found one rule called InNamedPolygon which would make sense to use, but when I set up rules to do it, nothing happens.

I know this is specifically the InNamedPolygon, because I have other nets specified in the same rule, and these all connect the way I would expect them to.

TLDR: Is there a way to make a rule that only applies to a part of a net (that happens to be in a polygon), and what does InNamedPolygon do?

I have attached an image of my current rules:
[image]

(I also have a lower priority rule that sets all polygon connections to relief and vias to direct so that other polygons have the normal relief connect)

The weirdest part is if I hit the Test Queries button, it highlights all the polygons I want to affect, but only applies the rule to the net class (IsSolidPour) and not the other specified polygons.

Comment: You'll probably get better support here: https://discord.me/altium

Comment: Saw this there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InNamedPolygon` returns the **primitives** of a polygon
Which means objects that are owned by the polygon in the hierarchy
I think you need `IsNamedPolygon` which returns the polygon itself.
The problem there is that when you query it they will all "light up" the same way, since, you see the polygon is what composes it. But it is not of polygon type itself.